# ESLINT export declaration causing question

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have one `info.js` file, containing two `Array` exports:

```
export const person = [{ name: 'john'}, {name: 'smith'}]
export const country = [{country: 'France'}, {country: 'UK'}]
```

It works if I require for ex: `person` as the following example:

```
import { person } from './info.js';
```

But I needed to separate `person` and `country` into their own `.js` files.

So, I made two files and wrote in `person.js` the following:

```
export const person = [{ name: 'john}, {name: 'smith'}]
```

But before I could even test it, ESLIN throws an error and shows me the below link:

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.18.0/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md

I found the below line makes the error go away:

```
// There is a default export.
const person = {...}
export { person as default }
```

But when I try to import `person` nothing works. I just cant get it to work at all.

Comment: Why did you need to make two files? And how did you change your import declaration?

Comment: @Bergi the missing `=` is a mistake here, I made the two files to make the data separate for my app. But I got the answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to import person? Default exports are imported as follows.

```
import person from './person'
```

If there is some reason to prefer a named export, you can disable eslint on the next line with the following comment

```
// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-default-export
import { person } from './person'
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I was trying to use `{}` braces when importing it.